# localhost:3000 doesn't display anything when run in Docker container

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, webpack

I’m trying to dockerize a MERN stack app, here’s the code in my client directory Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16
WORKDIR /usr/src/douban
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
ENV NODE_ENV=development
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

I build the image and run the container using the command

```
$ docker build -t douban-client .
$ docker run -p 3000:3000 -d douban-client
```

I use ‘docker ps’ and ‘docker logs’ command to test the running container, the output shows it runs successfully. However, when I open localhost:3000, it shows ‘This page isn’t working. localhost didn’t send any data.’

Can anyone tell me what’s wrong? really appreciate your help.

run docker ps:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE           COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
8cde2b46c18a   douban-client   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   heuristic_wescoff
```

run docker logs:

```
> my-app@0.1.0 start
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --config ./build/config/webpack.dev.js

ℹ Compiling STARTING
✔ STARTING: Compiled successfully in 9.08s
assets by path public/ 42.3 KiB
  assets by path public/*.png 19.3 KiB
    asset public/follower.png 8.86 KiB [emitted] [from: public/follower.png] [copied]
    asset public/systemprompt.png 6.16 KiB [emitted] [from: public/systemprompt.png] [copied]
    asset public/message.png 4.32 KiB [emitted] [from: public/message.png] [copied]
  asset public/defaultAvatar.webp 17 KiB [emitted] [from: public/defaultAvatar.webp] [copied]
  asset public/favicon.ico 3.5 KiB [emitted] [from: public/favicon.ico] [copied]
  asset public/index.html 2.1 KiB [emitted] [from: public/index.html] [copied]
  asset public/manifest.json 322 bytes [emitted] [from: public/manifest.json] [copied]
<w> [webpack-dev-server] "hot: true" automatically applies HMR plugin, you don't have to add it manually to your webpack configuration.
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Project is running at:
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Loopback: http://127.0.0.1:3000/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Content not from webpack is served from '/usr/src/douban/public' directory
<i> [webpack-dev-server] 404s will fallback to '/'
  asset public/robots.txt 67 bytes [emitted] [from: public/robots.txt] [copied]
assets by path js/*.js 11.1 MiB
  asset js/app.js 11.1 MiB [emitted] (name: app)
  asset js/node_modules_web-vitals_dist_web-vitals_js.js 13.1 KiB [emitted]
asset index.html 2.14 KiB [emitted]
orphan modules 905 KiB [orphan] 553 modules
runtime modules 30.1 KiB 18 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/ 3.32 MiB 751 modules
modules by path ./src/ 247 KiB
  modules by path ./src/views/ 118 KiB 26 modules
  modules by path ./src/components/ 47.9 KiB 20 modules
  modules by path ./src/app/ 14.4 KiB 8 modules
  modules by path ./src/api/*.ts 43.3 KiB 8 modules
  modules by path ./src/lib/ 8.37 KiB 7 modules
  modules by path ./src/styles/ 4.21 KiB 4 modules
  modules by path ./src/routes/*.tsx 7.03 KiB 3 modules
  modules by path ./src/*.tsx 1.42 KiB 2 modules
  ./src/reportWebVitals.ts 517 bytes [built] [code generated]
  ./src/providers/index.tsx 1.49 KiB [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.74.0 compiled successfully in 9067 ms
Type-checking in progress...
ℹ Compiling STARTING
✔ STARTING: Compiled successfully in 659.51ms
assets by status 55.5 KiB [cached] 9 assets
assets by status 11.1 MiB [emitted]
  assets by chunk 11.1 MiB (name: app)
    asset js/app.js 11.1 MiB [emitted] (name: app)
    asset app.6e417c1d373746eb7ad3.hot-update.js 847 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [hmr] (name: app)
  asset index.html 2.14 KiB [emitted]
  asset app.6e417c1d373746eb7ad3.hot-update.json 27 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [hmr]
Entrypoint app 11.1 MiB = js/app.js 11.1 MiB app.6e417c1d373746eb7ad3.hot-update.js 847 bytes
cached modules 4.44 MiB [cached] 1384 modules
runtime modules 30.1 KiB 18 modules
webpack 5.74.0 compiled successfully in 661 ms
Type-checking in progress...
No errors found.
No errors found.
```

I use webpack-dev-server, and I expose the host and post in the webpack config. My npm start script looks like this

```
"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --config ./build/config/webpack.dev.js"
```

webpack.dev.js:

```
const webpack = require("webpack")
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge")
const common = require("./webpack.common")

const SERVER_HOST = "127.0.0.1"
const SERVER_PORT = 3000

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "eval-source-map",
  devServer: {
    host: SERVER_HOST,
    port: SERVER_PORT,
    compress: true,
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: {
      index: "/",
    },
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization",
    },
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()],
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  As I understand it, the docker instance '127.0.0.1:3000' is not accessible via anywhere else.  You need to change the ```127.0.0.1:3000``` to ```0.0.0.0:3000```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using webpack-dev-server:

`<i> [webpack-dev-server] Loopback: http://127.0.0.1:3000/`

By default, the dev server runs on *127.0.0.1* to enable accessing localhost:XXXX on browsers. But this does not expose the content outside of a Docker container. You need the dev server to use *0.0.0.0* in order to be reachable from outside the container.

Depending on how you start your dev server, modify it to set the host to `0.0.0.0`. Example:

`"start": "webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000"`

---

**Edit:**

Or you can keep your `npm start` script the same but update your `webpack.dev.js`:

`const SERVER_HOST = "0.0.0.0"`

Source: https://dev.to/ku6ryo/run-webpackdevserver-in-docker-1mg5

Comment: I update the question with my webpack config. I've already exposed the host and port in my devServer config. Would you mind taking a look at it?

Comment: I also updated my answer in line with your update. The only problem I see with your set up is that you may have difficulties accessing localhost:3000 without Docker.